# How to truncate value in React Native Formik form field

Tags: react-native, formik, yup

I have a field where I only want the length to be 3 numbers long max. I am using Yup, however, it only notifies the user of the error, it doesn't stop the user from entering a number longer than desired.

To fix this I created a function that slices the input value. This looks like it works, it keeps the length in the form field to what I want, however, when I click submit the value for the field is the unsliced version.

Here is my code...

```
            <TextInput
              style={styles.text}
              value={_checkLength(values.number, 3)}
              onChangeText={handleChange('number')}
              onBlur={() => setFieldTouched('number')}
              placeholder="Number"
            />
```

My _checkLength function is simple...

```
_checkLength = (value, length) => {
  return value.slice(0, length)
}
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: you can call setFieldValue function inside onChangeText to update the value in the form.

Comment: Why not use maxLength prop in your Textnput?

Comment: Geeze, @CarlosJulioMartinezOrtega that worked, can't believe I missed that. So much simpler - lol.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this answer so people can see how to use `setFieldValue`, but @Carlos had the correct and obvious answer. That is to simply use `maxLength={num}`

---

Credit to @MohammedAshfaq . His answer is correct but I wanted to provide exact code that needs to be updated. The answer was to run `setFieldValue` by putting it in the `onChangeText` field. I had to pass in the value and then run my function using that passed in value. Now, when I submit it submits the proper value returned from the `_checkLength` function.

```
            <TextInput
              style={styles.text}
              value={values.number}
              onChangeText={(value) => setFieldValue('number', _checkLength(value, 3))}
              onBlur={() => setFieldTouched('number')}
              placeholder="Uniform Number"
            />
```